# Accidentally saved a .py file to name of my main program.This has overwritten my main program.Is there a way to retrieve my old code?

Tags: spyder

Accidentally "saved as" a .py file and replaced a main program file with the new one by mistake.Is there away to retrieve the main program in spyder?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) I'm very sorry, but unless you are using a version control program for your code (like git or mercurial), there's no way to retrieve your previous code in Spyder.